# TinyMCE completely blank if used in multiple vuetify dialogs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, tinymce

I'm trying to use TinyMCE in multiple dialogs, but whenever I switch dialogs, the TinyMCE becomes completely blank and I can't edit it.

I created this demo to reproduce the error that I get: https://codesandbox.io/s/tinymce-vue-demo-forked-nj4kdf?file=/src/App.vue

The two buttons are components that each have their own dialog. Clicking on one of the two shows the TinyMCE just fine. Clicking on the other gives that blank look.

I tried to add v-if to the tinyMCE, but what that did was that you would still get the blank look, but if you would bring up the same dialog again, it would function as normal. I still need to get rid of the problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

[It's a bug with tinymce](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue/issues/230) that the editor breaks when DOM elements are removed/added like with dialog elements.  A work around would be to use the `eager` prop on `<v-dialog>` to keep the DOM elements rendered regardless of the dialog visibility state.

```html
<v-dialog v-model="display" eager>
```

Comment: So I tried to add Eager. In the demo it works just fine, with both dialogs working just fine. But in my code, it slows stuff down to a crawl, and the tinyMCE never shows up now.